# index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0] with custom cell and SWTableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to add custom cells to a static `UITableViewController`. I use [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) to get the swipable cell and I'm using a custom -xib for the cell layout.

I seems to work fine when I only need to use one cell, but when there are more then one I get this: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'`

This happens when I use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when the second cell should appear (when I begin to scroll).

Here is my code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.images = selectedReport.image;

        imagesArray = [self.images.allObjects mutableCopy];

        self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];    

        [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PictureCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"PictureCell"];

    }

    - (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section
    {
        if(section == 0){
            return 10;
        }else if(section == 1){
            return imagesArray.count; //It is the second section which is dynamic
        }
        return 1;
    }


- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"PictureCell";

    if (indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 2)
    { //Takes the rows from the storyboard
        return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.row);
        NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.section);

        PictureTableViewCell *cell = (PictureTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; //Crash here when indexPath.row == 1


        [cell setCellHeight:cell.frame.size.height];
        cell.containingTableView = tableView;
        indexPath.section, indexPath.row];

        Image *tempImage = imagesArray[indexPath.row];        

        cell.image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:tempImage.image];
        cell.lblDescription.text = tempImage.image_description;

        cell.rightUtilityButtons = [self rightButtons];
        cell.delegate = self;

        return cell;

    }
}
```

I have checked that `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 2 when section == 1.

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Check your imagesArray will not empty

Comment: @NANNAV Sorry? I have checked that numberOfRowsInSection returns 2 when section is 1

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

or in **viewDidLoad**, register the class like

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"PictureCell"];

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PictureCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

Comment: Hi. But if I do this how can I connect it to my custom PictureTableViewCell and its properties?